# I'm having issues embedding a Carthage framework in my first mac app

Tags: swift, macos, carthage

I'm having issues loading the VLCKit framework I got from Carthage when my app starts. Here's the error I get:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @loader_path/../Frameworks/VLCKit.framework/Versions/A/VLCKit
  Referenced from: /Users/jonah/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-aucxagzvxytixgactnppqdecyphh/Build/Products/Debug/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/jonah/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-aucxagzvxytixgactnppqdecyphh/Build/Products/Debug/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/VLCKit.framework/Versions/A/VLCKit: code signature in (/Users/jonah/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-aucxagzvxytixgactnppqdecyphh/Build/Products/Debug/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/VLCKit.framework/Versions/A/VLCKit) not valid for use in process using Library Validation: mapped file has no Team ID and is not a platform binary (signed with custom identity or adhoc?)
    /Users/jonah/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-aucxagzvxytixgactnppqdecyphh/Build/Products/Debug/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/VLCKit.framework/Versions/A/VLCKit: code signature in (/Users/jonah/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-aucxagzvxytixgactnppqdecyphh/Build/Products/Debug/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/VLCKit.framework/Versions/A/VLCKit) not valid for use in process using Library Validation: mapped file has no Team ID and is not a platform binary (signed with custom identity or adhoc?)
    /Users/jonah/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-aucxagzvxytixgactnppqdecyphh/Build/Products/Debug/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/VLCKit.framework/Versions/A/VLCKit: stat() failed with errno=1
(lldb)
```

Here is my Cartfile:

```
binary "https://code.videolan.org/videolan/VLCKit/raw/master/Packaging/VLCKit.json" ~> 3.3.0
```

Comment: Can you post your `Cartfile`?

Comment: @luca_999 Updated the question to add the cartfile.